# How to show that set $B$ is a subset of $A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have the following two sets: $A=\{-l,....a,..b,....l\}$ and $B=\{a,....b\}$. I wanted to prove that $B$ is subset of $A$. I have tried the following way, I wounder whether it is the right one or not.

$a\in A$ $\land$ $a\in B$

$a\in A\cap B$

and similarly for $b$

$b\in A$ $\land$ $b\in B$

$b\in A\cap B$

which means that $B\subset A$.

Is it the right way to prove it or not?

Comment: What is the definition of "$\ldots$"?

Comment: this mean there are many elements belong to this as we wrote for real number for example $\mathbb{R}=\{1,2,3.....\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every element of $B$ is an element of $A$. This should be enough.

edit:
I will try to be more useful.
First of all, it seems like the question is not very well defined. As someone here already asked, what does $...$ mean here?

I will assume that $a<b$ are integers, and also that $|a|,|b| < |l|$ so that the question makes sense.

Now that we have established a formal setting for the question, lets continue to the proof.

Assume that $x \in B$ is some element. Then $x = a$ or $x = a + 1$ ... or $x = b$. In other words, $x$ is an integer such that $a \leq x \leq b$. As $A$ is the set of all integers with absolute value $\leq l$, and $l \geq |a|,|b|$ we conclude that $x \in A$.

This sums up the proof. I hope that both you and me understood the question correctly, because it seems to be a really strange one.

Comment: Yes I knew this, but I wanted to prove it mathematically that is why I put it here. By definition it is very clear but how mathematically we can prove it I wanted to know whether I am right in above or not?

Comment: I think we should agree on the problem first. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: Yes I have checked your update and I think I forgot to wrote that $a\leq b$ thanks for your updating it. I agree with the editing you have made in the question.